# jquery and font size

Tags: jquery, css

I noticed in the main jquery.js file there is a reference to `"fontSize"` - I'm noticing on one of my pages that the font size is not changing (no matter what value I put in the CSS).  Is it possible that the jQuery.js file is overriding it?

In the jQuery.js file:

```
f.left = b === "fontSize" ? "1em"
```

The version of jQuery is 1.6.4

Comment: I'd say it's pretty unlikely jQuery is *silently* changing your font size. Try reproducing / isolating the bug in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery source that block is commented:

```
    // If we're not dealing with a regular pixel number
    // but a number that has a weird ending, we need to convert it to pixels
```

So the code is executed when you give a "number that has a weird ending".

Try putting font-size: 16px !important; in the css and see if that works.

Comment: Esailija - I added the !important and that made it bigger (so that is good).  However, I can't seem to get it smaller.  I'm trying 8pt, 4pt, 1pt and they are all the same size.

Comment: Even putting 8px !important, 4px !important etc.. doesn't work?

Comment: correct!  However, I played around with some different fonts and noticed that it was able to get smaller.  I was using originally ms sans serif.  When I changed it to times new roman I did see a smaller size when I adjusted the size down.